# saving dynamic data in localstorage in html5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

In my mobile app (jquery mobile + phonegap), I have two select menus and when user select some options from that menus, I want to store that in local storage. I know the simple syntax of local storage like
    localStorage.setItem(key,value);
But i have no idea how to store dynamic data in local storage?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic meaning what?

For it to be "dynamic" then just update the localStorage item by running `localStorage.setItem(key,value)` using the same key and updating the value.

Make a function which gets all of the menus items and values (off or on, 0 or 1, false or true, or some string/integer) which runs `localStorage.setItem(key,value)` then call that function every time the menu is saved or updated.

Comment: I have two select menus and both are interlinked i.e. suppose in first menu there are 3 companies (A, B, C) and for each company there are different shades in second select menu. A has 3 shades (shade1, shade2, shade3), B has 2 shades and C has 1. Now, if i select company A from first selection menu and shade1 from second. I want to save these combinations in local storage (as we store in array). Now, if again i select some other combination it should be stored in local storage (it should not override the last one). Hope that you understand the problem?

Comment: If i get it correctly, what you are trying to do is to serialize an array with a lot of options, something like this: http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/